# Deactivate all buttons during execution - PyQt

Tags: python, user-interface, pyqt

I'm building a GUI with PyQt, and I'd like to make it possible to stop all the buttons doing anything while code is running. Lets say the user is copying a lot of data from a table - it would be easy for them to click another button while it is happening even if the cursor has changed to the egg timer. Any ideas or workarounds for this without going through all buttons and greying them out one by one? I'd be happy with a workaround too!

Thanks for any ideas,

Pete

Comment: Systematically put all buttons you create in a list, then iterate on the list to disable them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use a modal `QDialog`. From the [QDialog pyqt documentation](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/qdialog.html):

```
A modal dialog is a dialog that blocks input 
to other visible windows in the same application.
```

Also, [QProgressDialog](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/qprogressdialog.html) is a very convenient tool to handle blocking action in a very simple way. Here is an example :

```
from PyQt4 import QtGui, QtCore
from time import sleep

class Test(QtGui.QDialog):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Test, self).__init__(parent)
        button = QtGui.QPushButton("Button")
        hbox = QtGui.QHBoxLayout()
        hbox.addWidget(button)
        self.setLayout(hbox)
        button.clicked.connect(self.slot)

    def slot(self):
        progress = QtGui.QProgressDialog(self)
        progress.setWindowModality(QtCore.Qt.WindowModal)
        progress.setLabel(QtGui.QLabel("Doing things..."))
        progress.setAutoClose(True)
        for i in range(101):
             progress.setValue(i);
             sleep(0.05)
             if progress.wasCanceled():
                 break

if __name__=="__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    myapp = Test()
    myapp.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: I didn't make it clear but I'm talking about stuff going on within one dialog box. However, If I added a hidden modal QProgressDialog it could work (the code is slow enough that people could have time to click somewhere they shouldn't but not so slow that it really needs a progress indicator!). Thanks for your help!

Comment: In that case, if your long execution is not threaded, you don't need to do anything. If your main thread is busy running the code connected to your slot, the whole GUI is frozen and inputs will be ignored. Try replacing my `slot` method with `def slot(self): sleep(5)` and you'll see that all your inputs in the next five seconds after you click the button will be ignored.